# VSCode run JavaScript file line by line like REPL

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to run JavaScript/TypeScript file opened in VSCode line by line?

Like you press something like CMD+XXX+Enter and it runs the current line or code block?

So you can play with code interactively.

P.S.

I don't want to open JS console - I want to run the code (or code snippet) from the file currently opened in Editor.

It should be stateful, you run the first line, then second etc. "Code Runner" plugin not working that way, it forgets the previous run. So you ran the first line, then try to execute the second line - and it complains about undefined variables that were defined in the first one.

Answer (score 3):

VS Code doesn't has this feature built-in, but there are a lot of extensions for it. The most used is [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), but there are many others. For example, [Quokka.js](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WallabyJs.quokka-vscode) executes code as you type and it's the ideal to know the output of some little piece of code.

Comment: Quokka is a commercial plugin. While basic functionality is free, full version is paid.

Answer (score 1):

The new open source VS Code extension [Javascript REPL](https://github.com/axilleasiv/vscode-javascript-repl-docs) is promising.